# Array of a pointer in Go JSON marshalling

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I've the following code, where I want to just test whether I'm marshaling my JSON correctly or not:

```
package main
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

 
type TestFile struct {

        Download_Seconds        int                `json:"download_seconds"`                                                                             
        Name                    string             `json:"name"`                                                            
}

 
type TestFileList struct {

        File                    *TestFile          `json:"file"`                                                                                                                                                           
}


type TestSpec struct {

        Files                   []*TestFileList    `json:"files"`                                                                                                 

}

 

func main() {
         r := new(TestSpec)
         b, _ := json.Marshal(r)
         fmt.Println(string(b))

         MyJSON := &TestSpec{Files: []&TestFileList{File: &TestFile{Download_Seconds: 600, Name: "filename1"}, File: &TestFile{Download_Seconds: 1200, Name: "filename2"}}}

         b1, _ := json.Marshal(MyJSON)
         fmt.Println(string(b1))

}
```

I'm getting this error:

`.\go_json_eg2.go:28:32: syntax error: unexpected &, expecting type`.

`Line no: 28` for my code is `MyJSON := &TestSpec{Files: []&TestFileList{File: &TestFile{Download_Seconds: 600, Name: "filename1"}, File: &TestFile{Download_Seconds: 1200, Name: "filename2"}}}`

Fairly new to Go marshaling. I figured I'm doing this wrong `[]&TestFileList{File: &TestFile{Download_Seconds: 600, Name: "filename1"}, File: &TestFile{Download_Seconds: 1200, Name: "filename2"}}`.

How to fix this ?

Comment: @Zombo No this doesn't work. have you tested it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```golang
&TestSpec{
    Files: []*TestFileList{
        {File: &TestFile{Download_Seconds: 600, Name: "filename1"}},
        {File: &TestFile{Download_Seconds: 1200, Name: "filename2"}},
    },
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/I30Mm0CxrUT

Notice that besides the error pointed out by Zombo in the comments, you also left out the curly braces that delimit the individual elements in the slice, i.e. you have `{File: ..., File: ...}`, but it should be `{{File: ...}, {File: ...}}`.

You can read more about *Composite Literals* [here](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals).

Comment: I wanted to give another `+1` vote for not only answering, but also sharing some relevant resources to read from. This will definitely help